# Read a value for a key constructed in runtime

Tags: bash, dynamic, properties

I want to be able to read user input e.g. "Please enter your sex:", if the user enters **male** I want to read the property **male_interests** from a property file. On the other hand if the user enters **female**, i want to read **female_interests** from the property file. Is this possible? If yes, how?

I have already tried doing this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Please enter sex
read sex

property_name="$sex"_interests

source messages.properties

echo ${$property_name} ## I tried more crap but nothing worked
```

Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [BashFAQ/006](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006). `foo=1; bar=foo; echo ${!bar}`.

Comment: try replacing last line  as `echo ${sex%_interests}`?

Comment: or `echo ${!property_name}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BashFAQ/006](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006). `foo=1; bar=foo; echo ${!bar}`.
                    – 4ae1e1

or `echo ${!property_name}`
                    – VK Kashyap